# How to scale graphic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale

I have this graph but I want to scale the x-axis so it can be visualized better.

This is the function `abs(16*(\x)^3-24*(\x)^2+12*(\x)+1)`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for small domain and wide figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, % <---
    declare function = {f(\t)=abs(16*(\t)^3-24*(\t)^2+12*(\t)+1);},
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits=0.1,
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
    no marks, 
    domain=-1:1 % <---
            ]
\addplot {f(x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or at slightly bigger doman (by adding/changing ˙axisi options):

```
    domain=-1:2,               % changed
    restrict y to domain=0:50, % added
    samples=100                % added
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko, I see that you used pgfplots, I had not found out about its existence